# Craft License Management

Tags: license

A project I've been working on has just 'turned bad' - due to a number of reasons I've removed myself from involvement in the project. Earlier in the year I purchased an upgrade to the Craft license to that site for the Pro version, which I now don't want the client to have access to. I've removed the license.key file from their staging server, but they still have a backup of that file on their local machine.

According to the [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-transferring), if I use that license.key file on another website, the *old* client will just get a notification asking them if they want to transfer the license to their website (the one I've stopped working on), which gives me no control over it. Am I stuck with the client just being able to say "I want this license" and there being nothing I can do about it?

Shouldn't ownership & domain control of the license sit with the owner of that license rather than the person trying to take it?

Comment: I think you should contact support@buildwithcraft.com with these questions since no one here really can tell you what to do/how it is :)

Comment: As @naboovalley said, you'll want to contact support@buildwithcraft.com to get this resolved. It's not a technical question, more of a legal or ethical question. Discuss the issue with Pixel & Tonic for a real answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal/moral issues pertaining to license ownership. Contact support@buildwithcraft.com to discuss your options.